# Composite Pattern: Client treats collections of objects and individual objects uniformly

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

I am studying Java design patterns and with the Composite Pattern, I have read that the client treats collections of objects and individual objects uniformly. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means the client can perform an operation on an object without knowing if it is a single object or a collection of objects.  Say we have an object of type `Graphic` which can be an individual shape like `Circle` or `Rectangle` or a collection of shapes.  Then we can perform `graphic.scaleSizeBy(2)` to double the size.